# How to convert ObjectID to String in $lookup (aggregation)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have two collections, article and comments, the `articleId` in comments is a foreign key of `_id` in article.

```
db.collection('article').aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "comments",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "articleId",
      as: "comments"
    }
  },
  ...
])
```

but it doesn't work, because `_id` in article is an `ObjectID` and `articleId` is a string.

Comment: You cannot. It is impossible to "cast" any types in an aggregation pipeline. You need to fix the data instead so the "strings" are actually `ObjectId` values.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can achieve this using [**`$addFields`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) and [**`$toObjectId`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toObjectId/) aggregations which simply converts string id to mongo objectId

```
db.collection('article').aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "comments",
    "let": { "article_Id": "$_id" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$addFields": { "articleId": { "$toObjectId": "$articleId" }}},
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$articleId", "$$article_Id" ] } } }
    ],
    "as": "comments"
  }}
])
```

Or using [**`$toString`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toString/) aggregation

```
db.collection('article').aggregate([
  { "$addFields": { "article_id": { "$toString": "$_id" }}},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "comments",
    "localField": "article_id",
    "foreignField": "articleId",
    "as": "comments"
  }}
])
```

Comment: Is there any way to convert a foreignField or connectToField (with graphLookup) from an ObjectId to an String in a similar fashion?

Answer (score -7):

If you are using MongoDB 4.0 or above then you can directly use `$toString` on the `_id` field:

```
db.collection('article').aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "comments",
      localField: { $toString : "_id" },
      foreignField: "articleId",
      as: "comments"
    }
  },
  ...
])
```

But `MongoDB 3.6` doesn't support type conversion inside an aggregation pipeline. So `$toString` and `$convert` will only work with `MongoDB 4.0`.